# merge 2 matlab fig into 1 - how to use color , linewidth etc using copyobj

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to load 2 figures and merge them in one.

I know that I can do it by copy paste from one figure to another ,but through script?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276009/load-two-matlab-fig-figures-and-merge-them-in-one-file) , but it produces the 2 figures.How can I merge them in one (like using hold on)?
Also, can I change the axis dimension from one figure?Use only a part of its dimension?
And , how to change the color,style etc ?

----UPDATE---------------------------

My code right now is:

```
fig1=open('fig13.fig');
fig2=open('fig14.fig');

ax1=get(fig1,'Children');
ax2=get(fig2,'Children');


for i = 1 : numel(ax2) 

   ax2Children = get(ax2(i),'Children');
   tri=get(ax1(i),'Children');
   hold on;
   first=copyobj(tri, ax1(i));
   second=copyobj(ax2Children, ax1(i));

end


set(first,'color','g','marker','circle');
set(second,'color','b');
legend(first, {'first'}, 'Location','NorthWest', 'Color','g');
legend(second, {'second'}, 'Location','NorthWest', 'Color','b');
```

1) How can I specify the linewidth , marker,etc..Because using set(first,'marker','circle') for example doesn't work.

2) How can I use only a part of axis dimension of fig14 for example.
The fig13 for example (x axis) is (-8,4) and in fig14 is (-2 ,10).How can I do the merging graph to (-8,8)?

Comment: have you tried `hold on` and `hold off`? not sure it will work.

Comment: EDIT: It works!But you must use the loop (i din't used it!).But what about axis dimensions?And how I can define color and plot style?

Comment: ummmm don't know. I think all that is saved with .fig data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use :

set(first,'color','g','marker','o');

As for the axes you must produce new figures from the original code.