# how to remove third legend from merging two figures

Tags: matlab, plot

I am refering to this problem
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530943/merge-2-matlab-fig-into-1-how-to-use-color-linewidth-etc-using-copyobj).

My problem is that in the 3rd figure I create (which has the 2 figures) there are 3 legends.The 2 are ok but there is a 3rd legend (which is a legend from figure 1 or 2).
How can I erase it programatically?

```
fig1=open('fig1.fig');
fig2=open('fig2.fig');

ax1=get(fig1,'Children');
ax2=get(fig2,'Children');


for i = 1 : numel(ax2) 

   ax2Children = get(ax2(i),'Children');
   tri=get(ax1(i),'Children');
   hold on;
   first=copyobj(tri, ax1(i));
   second=copyobj(ax2Children, ax1(i));

end


set(first,'color','g','marker','o');
set(second,'color','b','marker','x');
legend(first, {'first'}, 'Location','NorthWest', 'Color','g');
legend(second, {'second'}, 'Location','NorthWest', 'Color','b');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `hasbehavior(tri,'legend',false)`  above

```
set(hasbehavior(temp,'legend',false)
```