# Prevent specific plot entry from being displayed on a MATLAB plot legend

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to prevent a specific plot entry from being displayed on a Matlab plot legend.

**Sample:**

```
% x and y are any plot data
for i=1:5
    plot(x,y);
    plot(x2,y2,'PleaseNoLegend!'); % I need to hide this from legend
end
legend('show');
```

Is there any flag I can set inside the plot command so this specific entry doesn't show up in legend?

Comment: `h=plot(...); hasbehavior(h,'legend','false')` at least for HG1, dunno about HG2.

Comment: Asking on behalf of another user: could you please be more specific? Is there any condition you want to set for not plotting?

Comment: I'm plotting in a for loop and also in another parts of the code, some plots are only auxiliary and I don't want it to show in the legend.

Comment: Error using hasbehavior. Behavior state must be logical or numeric.

Comment: Sorry, `'false'` should be `false`, which is just `0`.

Comment: It works, perfect! Can you please post it as answer?

Comment: Luis's solution seems more appropriate anyway:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'd say your idea is much more appropriate. Mine hides the handles for all purposes. I had no idea of `hasbehavior`. Post it!

Comment: @AndrasDeak But then again, `hasbehavior` seems to be only semi-documented?

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks, you convinced me:) I found [a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542770/how-to-remove-third-legend-from-merging-two-figures/15557925#15557925), but your answer here is preferable in my opinion, so I decided to add `hasbehavior` in order to have a full set of answers here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting the `'HandleVisibility'` property to `'off'`. Note that this hides the handles of those plots to all functions, not just to `legend`.

For example,

```
hold on
for k = 1:3
    x = 1:10;
    y = rand(1,10);
    x2 = x;
    y2 = y + 2;
    plot(x,y);
    plot(x2,y2,'--','HandleVisibility','off'); % Hide from legend
end
legend('show')
```

produces the graph

[image]

Comment: This approach may have unintended consequences to other functions. I would also recommend setting the legend for specific handles, e.g. something like `lh = plot(x1,y1,x2,y2); legend(lh(1), 'label1')`

Comment: @stephematician Yes, that's what my last line was meant to suggest. Your idea is better; you should post an answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [semi-documented function called `hasbehavior`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle-graphics-behavior), that allows you to ignore individual plots in a legend after you issued the plot command.

```
figure;
hold on;
for i=1:5
    plot(x,y);
    h = plot(x2,y2);
    hasbehavior(h,'legend',false);
end
legend('show');
```

The fact that it's semi-documented suggests that it *could* break sooner or later in a newer MATLAB version, so use with care. It might still be a convenient choice for certain applications.

As @stephematician noted, this MATLAB built-in is also unavailable in Octave, which might be another reason why the other answers are preferable.

Comment: This is a good answer! Only downside is it is not compatible with Octave (if you're into that sort of thing) ;)

Comment: @stephematician thank you:) Good point, I prefer cross-compatibility in principle, but I'm not too surprised that this isn't applicable for Octave, sorry:( (and thanks, Luis;)

Answer (score 4):

As Luis Mendo mentions (and I somehow missed this) the handle is hidden to all other functions in his answer, which will be ok in most situations, but an alternative solution which looks identical to the above and doesn't have this effect is:

```
k_values = 1:3;
h = nan(size(k_values));
x = 1:10;

hold on
for k = k_values
    y = rand(size(x));
    y2 = y + 2;
    h(k) = plot(x,y);
    plot(x,y2,'--');
end
hold off

legend(h, strcat('data', num2str(k_values')))
```

The final command sets the legend entry for each handle returned by the `plot(x,y)` command. The first argument is a 1x3 array of line handles which will appear in the legend, and the second argument is a 3x5 char matrix where each row is a label.

Comment: This should be the cleanest solution, as it doesn't rely on semidocumented features, and only manipulates legend generation specifically.

Comment: `legend(h, strcat('data', num2str(k_values.') ))` works for me

Comment: Just to state the obvious: the gist of the answer is the fact that an `h` array should be generated and `legend` called on this; in any practical application the user will have created a character array/cell for their legend texts anyway:)